# Close soft keyboard on iOS / Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, soft-keyboard

How can I close the soft keyboard on both Android and iOS?
It seems to linger after the input field is already gone ( moved on to the next view ).

Comment: Yet answered here:

[Close Keyboard][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, you must call:

```
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

when the user is done editing. You can tell when the user is done in the `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`
 function

On Android, hopefully someone else can give you a good answer.

Comment: Thank you :) now for android.. let's hope

Answer (score -1):

press the back arrow in order to exit the keyboard

Comment: Thanks, but i want to do this programmatically ;)

Comment: Here, we have developed applications for android tablets and we faced the same problem , there was nothing that we found so the back button was used. If you can find something post it please so code can be updated